# regex for getting up to but not including a character in output

Tags: php, regex

so basically i just need some help with my regex pattern, it works but it captures the opening parenthesis and i don't want it to do that. i need it to search up to that but no include it in the return. i have an array that i imploded and glued with an asterisk

```
$string = 'this is a test*Yes this is a (poor test)*But its easy';
```

now i want to, in one fail swoop get all text up to and not including the ( and split it by * 
this is what i have at the moment, which almost works but it is including the ( in the output.

```
$delimiter = '/.+[(*]/U';
```

oh and i am using preg_match_all()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, match

```
[^(]+
```

instead. Which will match a sequence of characters that are *not* an opening parenthesis. So 
matching will stop right before the next opening parenthesis.

Comment: awesome it works thanks, although it removes that opening parenthesis. is there a way to stop that ?

Comment: Essentially you want a split at `(?=\()` if I understand you correctly. But a match all with `\(?[^(]+` might work too.

Comment: perfect! thank you so much, can you explain \(?[^(]+ to me please in english lol :P

Comment: An optional opening parenthesis, followed by at least one non-parenthesis.